# Using json variable

Tags: php, json

How do I use json variable in php.

```
$filePath = '/home/user/public_html/uploads/samplefile.txt'

echo '{"status":"success", "fileName" : "'.$filePath.'"}';
```

Say I would like to use it this way.

```
$mail->addattachment($fileName);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to first deserialize the json data into a PHP array.

```
$json_string = "...."; //this is your json string

$json_data = json_decode($json_string); // decode into an array
$mail->addattachment($json_data['filename']);
```

Comment: When i try to echo $json_data['filename'] i get Cannot use object of type stdClass as array.

Comment: Adding true fixed the problem $json_data = json_decode($json_string, true);

Answer (score 0):

While @xbonez answer is correct, you could use it the way you specified, but it's not recommended:

```
$json = <<<JSON
{"status":"success", "fileName" : "/home/user/public_html/uploads/samplefile.txt"}
JSON;

extract(json_decode($json, TRUE));

echo $fileName;
```

Comment: Thanks but I'll accept xbonez answer since he's the first one to give an answer to my question.